# R language, how to extract from matrices in the list and merge into new matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose a list called list_x is made up of 10 different matrices, the dim of all these matrices is 5 * 3.
Now, what I want to do is:

- Extract the first column of each matrix and vertically merged into a new matrix A
- Extract the second column of each matrix and vertically merged into a new matrix B
- Extract the third column of each matrix and vertically merged into a new matrix C

I thought of it, but just can write here

```
sapply(list_X, function(x) x[,1])
```

Thank for any help.

Comment: Hi Grace, can you please add a [Minimum Working Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with data to your question.

Comment: list_X <- list(matirx1, matirx2, matirx3)  # #actually, the number of matrix is 10
> list_X
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    6   11
[2,]    2    7   12
[3,]    3    8   13
[4,]    4    9   14
[5,]    5   10   15

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   11   16   21
[2,]   12   17   22
[3,]   13   18   23
[4,]   14   19   24
[5,]   15   20   25

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   36   41   46
[2,]   37   42   47
[3,]   38   43   48
[4,]   39   44   49
[5,]   40   45   50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list_X <- replicate(10, matrix(1:15, 5, 3), simplify = F)
```

A little dirty but this will do the trick (not sure what exactly you mean by vertically merge).

```
lapply(1:3, function(y) sapply(1:10, function(x) list_X[[x]][,y]))
```

Comment: two amazing commond lines, sample but realize complex function. by the way, vertically merge, how to say, like cbind() function, not clear expression:PThank you!

Comment: Then put a transpose before the `sapply`, like `t(sapply(...))`

Comment: Got it, your code level is so good. However, until today I know lapply(1:3...) can accept vector...